# Using dynamic templates in custom module

Tags: 9

I have created a custom Drupal 9 module, and I would like for this module to use different template files basing on a variable.
I have looked at `hook_theme()` and I think the pattern return value might be what I am looking for, but I can't seem to make it work.

#### testpage.module

````php
function testpage_theme() {
  return array(
    'testpage' => array(
      'template' => 'testpage',
      'variables' => array('items' => array(), 'title' => NULL),
      'pattern' => 'testpage__'
    )
  );
}  

### Controller file (Testpage.php)

```php
namespace Drupal\testpage\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class Testpage extends ControllerBase {

  public function Render($name) {
    $result = "Lorem ipsum";
    $build = array(
      '#theme' => array('testpage__'.$name, 'testpage'),
      '#items' => $result,
      '#title' => 'Testpage',
      '#cache' => [
        'max-age' => 0
      ]
    );

    return($build);
  }
}
````

I created three template files in a "templates" folder.

- testpage.html.twig
- testpage--test.html.twig
- testpage--test2.html.twig

Basing on `$name`, it should use the matching template file. However, it is always just using the markup from the testpage.html.twig. When `$name` is equal to `"test"`, it should use the testpage--test.html.twig file; when `$name` is equal to `"test2"`, it should use the testpage--test2.html.twig file. And it would be great if it would use the testpage.html.twig file as a fallback if a matching template does not exist.
I thought this was possible with the *pattern* return value, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly. Am I missing something, or is this not possible?

Comment: one thing u could definitely do is to pass `$name` to the template and in the template use sth. like `{{ include('template-' ~ name ~  '.html.twig') }}`

Comment: Yeah thought about that solution too, but that would require that the file exists. I could of course check in the controller if the twig file exists, and pass that info to the render array, and use that logic in the twig template.

Comment: AFAIK `pattern` [doesn't exist anymore](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2063793) and is just a left-over in the docs. Instead use [hook_theme_suggetions_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.8.x)